# Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that $f(M)=M^k$ is differentiable.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, solution-verification, operator-theory

*Question:*
Let $M \in  \mathbb{R}^{d \times   d}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ prove that $f(M)=M^k$ is differentiable.

*My Answer:*
In order to prove that $f(M)=M^k$ is differentiable we have to show by definition that $\forall H \in  \mathbb{R}^{d \times  d}$,  $f(M+H)$ can be written as follow: $f(M+H)=f(M)+L(H)+o(H)$ with $L(H)$ a linear mapping in $H$ on $o(H)$ verifying $\lim_{ H \to 0} \frac{||| o(H)|||}{|||H|||}=0$ (with $||| \cdot ||| $ the operator norm).

-We note that $(M+H)^k$ is a [matrix polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial) thus it can be decomposed as follow:
$(M+H)^k$
$=M^k$ (basically the case where the degree of $H$ is zero)
+all the component of the polynomial where $H$ appears with a degree $1$
+all the component of the polynomial where $H$ appears with a degree $>1$
-Now it is obvious that all the component of the polynomial where $H$ appears with a degree $1$ are a linear mapping for $H$ (so this is $L(H)$).

Now we want to prove that: $\lim_{ H \to 0} \frac{||| o(H)|||}{|||H|||}=0$ and here is my difficulty, how can i do it? I try to justify it like this.
$o(H)$=all the component of the polynomial where $H$ appears with a degree $\geq 2$ hence once divided by $H$ it can be "simplified" and we will get a matrix polynomial with his lowest degree equal to $1$ so it will goes to zero.
Intuitively it makes sense but i am not sure that this is very rigurous.

So is my prove is correct? And more precissely I would like to have help concerning the last part.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but need to formalize it. It would help to 1) Write an actual formula for $L(H)$ and 2) Show that the limit is $0$. For the second, you can use the fact that $\|A B\|\leq \|A\|\|B\|$

Comment: Thk for your answer but this is precisely where i am stuck, and saddly I have soon an exams and a lot more to learn. So a details answer will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove what you want, you need to use the property $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$ of the operator norm, together with the triangle inequality it will give you an estimate $\|o(H)\| \leq \sum_{i = 2}^k \binom{k}{i} \|H\|^i \|M\|^{n - i}$.

Comment: Thk a lot for your time can you wrotte a more details answer so I can mark my problem as solved by selecting your answer+ i ve soon the final exams and lot of things to learn so it will help me a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can define notation to write things out explicitly. $k=0,1$ are trivial so suppose $k>1$. For any $b\in\{0,1\}^k$, define $[M,H]_b $ to be the matrix product of $k$ matrices where the $j$th matrix is $M$ iff $b_j=0$ and otherwise the matrix is $H$. Then
\begin{align}
&(M+H)^k \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{b\in\{0,1\}^k: \sum_p b_p = i} [M,H]_b
\\
&= M^k + \sum_{j=1}^k M^{j-1} H M^{k-j} + \sum_{i=2}^k \sum_{b\in\{0,1\}^k: \sum_p b_p = i} [M,H]_b.
\end{align}
Put $L(H)=\sum_{j=1}^k M^{j-1} H M^{k-j}$. For the error term you can proceed as the other answer using the above formula.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer !